# For what uses do we need `sys` module in python?

Tags: python

I'm a bit experienced without other languages but, novice with Python. I have come across made codes in jupyter notebooks where `sys` is imported.

I can't see the further use of the sys module in the code. Can someone help me to understand what is the purpose of importing `sys`?
I do know about the module and it's uses though but can't find a **concise reason of why is it used in many code blocks without any further use.**

Comment: [sys](https://www.python-course.eu/sys_module.php)
I read such few docs of python too.

P.S. I had seen it before in my webdev backend partner's code. I couldn't see further implementations of the module in that code either.

Comment: [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) official documentation might help.

Comment: There's no reason to import it if it's not explicitly used.

Comment: e.g.I had seen a Stanford NLP course notebook without sys imported and never used further.

Comment: I'm a newbie on Stack. I complied with stack suggestions for framing the question and I can't see any issues with it. I would like to know the reason in words rather than downvoting the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing declared within `sys` is actually used, then there's no benefit to importing it. There's not a significant amount of cost either.

Comment: I had seen a  Stanford NLP course notebook without sys imported and never used further. Are you sure about that answer?

Comment: @VedantPanchal: yes.

Answer (score 1):

`Sys` module is a rather useful module as it allows you to work with your System and those things. Eg:

- You can access any command line arguments using `sys.argv[1:]`
- You can see the Path to files.
- Version of your Python Interpreter using `sys.version`
- Exit the running code with `sys.exit`

Mostly you will use it for accessing the Command Line arguments.

Comment: yes, but I couldn't see those either. I read about these in the doc. Thanks though!

Comment: Sometimes, it is not the code directly needing it but for proper functioning, and requirement of some other library, or maybe, most often, people just import it thinking that they might need it but don't end up using it. So, it might be there just by mistake. You can check removing the import sys and running the code to see if any errors pop up.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm a new pythonista bro, I learned to import it whenever I want to exit the program with a nice exit text in red**

```
import sys

name = input("What's your name? ")
if name == "Vedant":
    print(f"Hello There {name}.")
else:
    sys.exit(f"You're not {name}!")
```

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I did read such stuff in the docs. Sorry to not be clear with the question.
I have edited it to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

The sys includes "functions + variable " to help you control and change the python environment @runtime.
Some examples of this control includes:

1- using other sources data as input via using:

```
sys.stdin
```

2- using data in the other resources via using:

```
sys.stdout
```

3- writing errors when an exception happens, automatically in :

```
sys.stderr
```

4- exit from the program by printing a message like:

```
sys.exit("Finish with the calculations.")
```

5- The built-in variable to list the directories which the interpreter will looking for functions in them:

```
sys.pasth
```

6- Use a function to realize the number of bytes in anonymous datatype via:

```
sys.getsizeof(1)
sys.getsizeof(3.8)
```